# Cant find app at google play with all devices

Tags: android, google-play-services

I released an Android-App at google play. In this app you can use the telephone function.
But I want that this app can be used with all available devices, including tablets without SIM-card.
After relesing this app at google play, i cant find it with my Samsung TAB2.
My smartphone and a tablet with SIM-card find it without problems.

Is there a configoption, that every device can load my app?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

in your manifest then apps that do not have a sim card should be able to use it